# Python main control

Tags: python, date, time, controls, daemon

I've run into an issue and am looking for guidance from a few veterans. I've written a program in python that I'd like to run only periodically. I'm going to upload it to my sever, and what I'd like for it to do is to run every Monday through Friday, and every 5 minutes between 9:30 and 4.

Basically I've written modules to query the market, and evaluate securities that I own. I don't want to tax the servers, so every 5 minutes should be fine.

What I want is some advice on how I should arrange the main sequence. Should I run the program from a continuous loop that just checks the time? Or should I run the code, scheduled from a daemon? Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An application should do one thing, and it should do it well.
>    
>    - *[`unix philosophy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)*

---

Unless there is any true reason for keeping the application running 24/7 (data consistency or such) I'd really recommend you to use a daemon to fire it up according to some schedule.

Your application should focus on querying the market in an efficient manner, not keeping track of when to do this.

---

*Note: Just be careful so that you don't start a new instance to often, before the previous instance of your python script has finished. "do one thing, and do it well" comes into mind here.*

Answer (score 2):

cron can *easily* handle that timing (although 2 entries will be required), so unless you have extreme low-latency requirements it's best to have it invoke the script on demand.

Answer (score 1):

You should angle for the latter (schedule the task to run periodically), since the former takes up processing power that could be used to handle peak traffic. (And if the script is resource hungry, then you're just robbing processing capacity.)

One project I've heard of that can do that pretty easily is the [Celery project](http://celeryproject.org/). I haven't personally used it, but I hear it's pretty good.